# What is the difference between AssemblySwConnector and DelegationSwConnector in AUTOSAR architecture?

Tags: architecture, embedded, autosar, automotive

My goal is to create an interface between a SW component and a BSW module.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, you only need the `AssemblySwConnector`. Software-components are wired to service-components (that represent the BSW modules) in the **flat** ECU Extract when `DelegationSwConnector`s are already resolved.

But anyway, a `DelegationSwConnector` is used to support the creation of a **hierarchy** of software-components. This can be useful for design purposes (you can take simple blocks to compose a complex overall semantics that, in turn, can be used for further compositions).

These hierarchical compositions created for design purposes are flattened for the actual integration on an ECU and the `DelegationSwConnector`s are removed in the process of flattening.

You can find more information about the flattening approach in the specification document of the AUTOSAR System Template.